# Half of half cycle of sine wave

Tags: matlab, sine

How can I identify the increasing and decreasing side of half cycle of sine wave using MATLAB code (.m file). For example the flag should set 1 if the amplitude of sine wave is increasing from 0 deg to 90 deg and should set 0 when amplitude is decreasing from 90 deg to 180 deg.[image]

Comment: sign and gradient: 0-90 = ++; 90-180 = +-; 180-270 = --; 270-360=-+

Comment: From \$ 180^o \$ to \$ 270^o \$ do you want to consider that as increasing (because the absolute value is) or reducing?

Comment: well, talking in terms of logic - In the interval 0-90 , if the absolute value of (current value - previous value >=0) then flag should be 1. Otherwise 0.

Comment: @WarrenHill i want to divide the entire cycle into 4 segments, absolute value doesn't matter

Comment: @MITURAJ in the model I use, previous value cannot be taken

Comment: @Chu a perfectly good *answer* camouflaged as a comment.

Comment: @ruveena This cannot be done as a memoryless system, since there are two possible solutions for any given value. The best you can do by sampling a single point is to determine if you're in the positive or negative half-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by taking derivative of the sine function either in matlab code or du/dt block in simulink

```
grad = diff (sin(x));
if (sin(x)>0 && grad>0)  
    \\0 to 90 deg
if (sin(x)>0 && grad<0)
     \\90 to 180 deg
if (sin(x)<0 && grad<0)
      \\180 to 270 deg
if (sin(x)>0 && grad>0) 
      \\270 to 360 deg
```